Generate a three-dimensional table with data that satisfy a certain relation between them
I need to generate a 3 dimensional table of two variables x1 and x2 such that for any point x1, x2 must be smaller than x1^2+a^2, where a is some given constant. Something like the following t=Table[{x1,x2,f[x1,x2]},{x1,0.1,1,0.1},{x2,x2<x1^2+a^2}].
How can I impose this condition in a simple way? I tried to do t=Table[{x1,x2,f[x1,x2]},{x1,0.1,1,0.1},{x2,Min[x1^2+a^2]}] but it does not give the right result.
Thanks in advance!

It sounds like x2 is an output, not an input.

What do you expect elements like {x1,x2,f[x1,x2]} to actually be? Given the constant a and the value of x1, you can choose an x2, so what is f[x1,x2] supposed to be? Why aren't the elements just pairs instead of triples?

May be I did not understand the question well. Will delete this if so. Just let me know.
But what is wrong with adding an explicit check inside the table?
Instead of
t = Table[{x1, x2}, {x1, 0.1, 1, 0.5}, {x2, 0.1, 1, .5}]


do
a = .4;
t = Table[If[x2 < x1^2 + a^2, {x1, x2}, Nothing[]], {x1, 0.1, 1, 0.5}, {x2,0.1, 1, .5}]



Thanks a lot! This solves my problem.

Do you know how I can require this condition to hold within a certain precision interval, meaning not only for the point (x1,x2) where x2 < x1^2 + a^2, but in a region near it? Because when I try to plot the result apparently there are still infinite terms that remain in the vicinity of each interval [x1-t,x1+t] and [x2-t,x1-t] for very small t.
